# GA-H170N-WIFI M.2 connector shared with SATA?

Tags: motherboard, sata, m.2

So I'm putting together a parts list for a new home server that also functions as the house's NAS. The MB I've been considering is the [Gigabyte GA-H170N-WIFI](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5552#sp) but I'm getting confused about how many actual storage related ports it has.

I get that it has 2x SATA Express ports which can be used as-is **or** each as 2x standard SATA 6Gb/s ports plus an additional 2x SATA 6Gb/s ports. From the specs page alone, it would also seem that it has an M.2 connector that I could use for a boot drive SSD for a max of 7 total drives (1 SSD and 6 HDD).

However, the [manual](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-z170n(h170n)-wifi_e.pdf) on page 16 makes it seem like the M.2 might in some cases be shared or otherwise incompatible with a drive on the SATA3_0 port.  Here's a snippet from the manual:

[image: GA-H170N-WIFI Manual snippet]

I plan to operate the board in AHCI mode. My interpretation of this table is that I'm fine as long as my M.2 drive is PCIe x4 or PCIe x2, but not SATA.  Is that right? If so, it seems like an odd limitation. Can anyone explain?

Comment: If you connect something to the M.2 port then in most cases that ends up disabling a SATA port.